# Rvest - Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "factor"

Tags: r, rvest

I am using the below rvest code:

```
library(rvest)

URL <- "http://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp" #Feed page

WS <- read_html (URL) #reads webpage into WS variable

URLs <- WS %>% html_nodes ("a:nth-child(1)") %>% html_attr("href")         %>% as.character() # Get the CSS nodes & extract the URLs 

URLs <- paste0("http://www.soccerstats.com/",URLs) 

grepl("pmatch", oversdf$URLs)

URLs <-subset(oversdf, grepl("pmatch", oversdf$URLs),stringsAsFactors       =       FALSE)

Catcher1 <- data.frame(FMatch=character(),TotalGoals=character    (),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Start of for loop

for (i in URLs) {

WS1 <- read_html(i)
FMatch <- WS1 %>% html_nodes("H1") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
TotalGoals <- WS1 %>% html_nodes(".trow3+ .trow2 td~ td+ td font b") %>%     html_text() %>% as.character()
temp <- data.frame(FMatch,TotalGoals)
Catcher1 <- rbind(Catcher1,temp)
cat("*")

}
```

When it tries to run the loop I get the error:

Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "factor"

Looking at forum posts I need to use stringsAsFactors = FALSE, as my dataframe will be storing the field data as factors instead of strings.

The only place I can think that its left to go is on the temp df:

temp <- data.frame(FMatch,TotalGoals)

But however I try apply it to the above df it syntax errors, any ideas ?

(Obviously I'm a newbie to this so I might be wrong about the above is whats causing the error, just looks like it is from the various forums posts I have read)

Cheers

Comment: Anyone any ideas ?

Comment: Hi @anotherfred, don't suppose you have any idea on the above error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically the issue is with setting up the HTML environment within each loop. To get around this issue I used `html_session()` at the beginning of each loop and fed that to `html_nodes()`:

```
for (i in URLs) {

  WS1 <- html_session(i)
  FMatch <- html_nodes(WS1, "h1") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
  TotalGoals <- html_nodes(WS1, ".trow3+ .trow2 td~ td+ td font b") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
  temp <- data.frame(FMatch,TotalGoals)
  Catcher1 <- rbind(Catcher1,temp)
  cat("*")
}
```

Which returns:

```
R> Catcher1
                       FMatch TotalGoals
1      Santa Cruz vs Criciuma       2.07
2         FC Kiffen vs FC KTP       3.08
3       Furth B vs Augsburg B       2.00
4          Vikingur R. vs IBV       3.67
5  IA Akranes vs KR Reykjavik       4.00
6      Hafnarfjordur vs Valur       2.84
7        Valerenga B vs Skeid       2.25
8      Constanta vs Voluntari       1.75
9         Syrianska vs Norrby       3.46
10          Osters IF vs GAIS       3.14
11 Sleipner vs Linkoping City       2.94
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I see both methods working, having some adjustments made. The first problem is that in the initial code [html_nodes("H1")] "H1" was indicated instead of the true "h1". So this has to be corrected.

And the second problem is related to wrong type of "URLs". Namely, it has the following properties:

```
> typeof(URLs)
[1] "list"
> length(URLs)
[1] 1
```

Meanwhile, I would like it to be:

```
> typeof(URLs)
[1] "character"
> length(URLs)
[1] 10 #or some other number
```

Thus I made the following workaround:

```
n<-nrow(URLs)
URLs2<-character()
for (i in 1:n) {
  URLs2[i]<-as.character(URLs[i,1])
}
```

This made the initial version working. Here is the full code (thank you for a nice example, by the way):

```
library(rvest)

URL <- "http://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp" #Feed page

WS <- read_html (URL) #reads webpage into WS variable

URLs <- WS %>% html_nodes ("a:nth-child(1)") %>% html_attr("href")         %>% as.character() # Get the CSS nodes & extract the URLs 

URLs <- paste0("http://www.soccerstats.com/",URLs) 

oversdf <- data.frame(URLs=URLs)

rownames(oversdf)  #returns a vector of row names in the overs data.frame:

URLs <-subset(oversdf, grepl("pmatch", oversdf$URLs),stringsAsFactors       =       FALSE)

write.csv(URLs,file=paste(getwd(),"/sportURLs.csv",sep=""),row.names=FALSE)

Catcher1 <- data.frame(FMatch=character(),TotalGoals=character    (),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

##################################
#start of workaround
n<-nrow(URLs)
URLs2<-character()
for (i in 1:n) {
  URLs2[i]<-as.character(URLs[i,1])
}

#Start of for loop

for (i in URLs2) {

#end of workaround
#######################################

WS1 <- read_html(i)
FMatch <- WS1 %>% html_nodes("h1") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
TotalGoals <- WS1 %>% html_nodes(".trow3+ .trow2 td~ td+ td font b") %>%     html_text() %>% as.character()
temp <- data.frame(FMatch,TotalGoals)
Catcher1 <- rbind(Catcher1,temp)
cat("*")

}
```

Which returns:

```
> Catcher1
                               FMatch TotalGoals
1      Dep. Espanol vs Comunicaciones       2.22
2          San Martín B. vs Ituzaingó       1.77
3      Leandro N. Alem vs Def. Unidos       2.03
4     Dep. Laferre vs Central Córdoba       2.44
5     J.J. Urquiza vs Sport. Italiano       2.53
6       Excursionistas vs Berazategui       2.56
7                 Dock Sud vs Midland       1.74
8               Dep. Armenio vs Luján       1.47
#and so on
```